# Retrieving dicom files in wireless Network from server

Tags: dicom

I am trying to retrieve Dicom from Server.

I have a Conquest server. I am trying to retrieve images from this server to our own application.

But its showing the error.

The AE title which i entered in ACRAENAMA list is not Authenticated.

I am able to send dicom files from my application to server.

Comment: who issues the error, Conquest or your client? what do you use for retrieving?

Answer (score 1):

Well,
It is true for different implementations, not just your server that the AE title needs to be unique. We're using Leadtools in both our SCP and SCU and our code based on their [demos](http://demo.leadtools.com/MedicalViewer) always rejects connections if the AE title is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Conquest in a while, so please take this with a grain of salt. Look in the configuration for Conquest for a list of allowed AEs to retrieve images from your server, and have your application's AE name in that list.

If it is in the list, try using DCMtk's command line tools (at http://www.dcmtk.org) to do it manually, tru

If those fail, check:

- Firewalls (client and server)
- DICOM ports (standard one for the server is 104, make sure it wasn't accidentally set to something funny)

Comment: thanks dude...i am able to get the images from server .the AE title which i added for Sever in wireless is same as LAN. so i changed the AE title with Different Name..then its worked fine...no problem...so conclusion of my problem adding AE title in server must be unique....

Comment: Ah, yeah - AE Titles have always given me problems, too. The DICOM Specs are horrible to read and understand. I feel like I need a lawyer to go through it! So a lot of bizarre little specs with them get covered up.